# XNA 4.0 Ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c#, xna-4

Скажите, я скачал и установил XNA (последнею версию, с сайта Microsoft). И когда заходил скомпилировать проект вылезла ошибка.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А ответ [здесь](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/error-on-new-xna-4-0-game-project-no-suitable-graphics-card-found). На первой ссылке в гугле...

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё заработало.